# Question about orthogonal projection in terms of Hermitian product

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

For example, in $\Bbb R^n$, both

$$\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\|w\|^2}w \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\langle w,v\rangle}{\|w\|^2}w$$

are projections of $v$ on $w$, but in $\Bbb C^n$ only the first is right. What makes this difference?

I've found an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2013439/533661), but I'm still don't understand why the first is complex linear, whereas the second is complex-skew-linear would make the difference. And help, thanks!

Comment: Only the first is the orthogonal projection. The second is not orthogonal.

Comment: You are looking for a vector $x$ such that $\langle x,w\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$.  The first expression satisfies that, but the second does not.  You might say - what if I wanted $\langle w,x\rangle=\langle w,v\rangle$ instead?  It turns out that again the first works but the second does not (this time using the skew-linearity).  Substitute for $x$ in both equations and you will see that the first works both times, but the second does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it depends on a *convention* about linearity of the Hermitian form. Usually, mathematicians use the 'first entry convention', i.e., the first entry is linear, while the second entry is antilinear:

$$\langle cv,w\rangle=c\langle v,w\rangle,\qquad\langle v,cw\rangle=\bar c\langle v,w\rangle$$

Physicists, on their turn, often use the 'second entry convention', i.e.,

$$\langle v,cw\rangle=c\langle v,w\rangle,\qquad\langle cv,w\rangle=\bar c\langle v,w\rangle.$$

So, in the mathematicians convention, your first formula is the right one for the orthogonal projection onto $\Bbb Cw$, because the *orthogonal projection* is normally assumed to be *linear* and *not antilinear*, while in the physicists convention it's the second one. I have no idea of the historical reasons for this discrepancy, though.

Anyway, it's probably possible to consider a somewhat unorthodox 'antilinear orthogonal projection' and see what happens, but I believe that kind of trouble isn't what you are looking for right now! =]